# Terraform error No default VPC found in this region

Tags: amazon-web-services, amazon-vpc, terraform-provider-aws

I'm following the PluralSight course "[Terraform - Getting Started](https://app.pluralsight.com/courses/cc6552b7-fc1c-4dfe-a3f3-635c8a0c4528/table-of-contents)" and in it they refer to this terraform file [module_three.tf](https://github.com/ned1313/Getting-Started-Terraform/blob/master/m3/module_three.tf) which states the following:

*I have changed the original value `us-east-1` to my selected region `eu-west-2`...*

```
variable "region" {
  default = "eu-west-2"
}
```

...and...

```
#This uses the default VPC.  It WILL NOT delete it on destroy.
resource "aws_default_vpc" "default" {

}
```

The commands `terraform init` and `terraform plan` execute as expected (and as described in the course), but `terraform apply` produces this output:

```
aws_default_vpc.default: Creating...

Error: No default VPC found in this region.
```

**How can I determine the default VPC in a given region and how can I specify a default VPC for my region?**

Having to ask that question appears to go against the AWS documentation, as in their section [Default VPC and default subnets](https://docs.aws.amazon.com/vpc/latest/userguide/default-vpc.html) they clearly state:

> If you created your AWS account after 2013-12-04, it supports only
> EC2-VPC. In this case, you have a *default* VPC in each AWS Region. A
> default VPC is ready for you to use so that you don't have to create
> and configure your own VPC. You can immediately start launching Amazon
> EC2 instances into your default VPC. You can also use services such as
> Elastic Load Balancing, Amazon RDS, and Amazon EMR in your default
> VPC.

Comment: It sounds like either your account was created before `2013-12-04`, or at some point the default VPC in your account, in the `eu-west-2` region, has been deleted. On that very page you linked to, if you just scroll down a bit, there are instructions for creating the default VPC if it does not already exist.

Answer (score 1):

This is because terraform is not finding any Default VPC in the region.
you can add Default VPC as follows

```
aws ec2 create-default-vpc
```

Answer (score -2):

Followed [these instructions](https://docs.aws.amazon.com/vpc/latest/userguide/default-vpc.html#create-default-vpc) and created a default VPC.

I had assumed the VPC was defined by AWS in a repository style, but it is actually just an entry created in the account's own list of VPCs.